# neural network check plastic parts

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

neural networks are used to generalize and classify...
I have a little experience with classify digits...
[Using neural nets to recognize handwritten digits](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)

i want to use a network to check plastic parts.
I have a videostream of production from these plastic parts.

should i train the network with many videos of correct plastic parts to get positive output and random videos to get negative output?

If you have any books or links i would be happy to see them.

**EDIT**
It looks like i asked a bit stupid...

During production, wrong plastic parts can be created and these should be recognized by network. There are a lot of mistakes can happen during production, so i think 
it only makes sense to train the network with correct plastic parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convolution neural network would be my recommendation.

You should show individual parts with similar background and lighting.

The training has to be done on both good and bad parts - a sufficient random sampling of both.  You should also set aside a test set once your CNN is trained so you can evaluate it.

You'll want to generate a confusion matrix from the test data so you'll know the rate of false positives, false negatives, correct, and incorrect classifications.

Comment: i edit the question.. 
I hope you can understand me now  ^^

Comment: That's even worse.  What does "wrong" mean?  Dimensionally wrong?  Misshapen?  Material problems?

Comment: Worse means: It is not the same as the correct plastic part on a visual basis. It's misshapen. I want to use the network for a visual qualitycheck

Comment: Okay. It’s not the material that matters; it’s the dimensional part. That could work. Use a convolutions neural network. Show pictures of YOUR parts, preferably on the same background with the same lighting. Will the parts be separated on a conveyor belt?  That would be best.

Comment: Yes, the parts are separated on a conveyor belt... Okay, thanks, i will try it with cnn!